# Can't get Spark NLP working on Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, nlp, databricks, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I've done the following:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('Amazon ETL') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.4.5') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Plus...

```
import sparknlp
from sparknlp.annotator import *
```

and I get this error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwtW.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kelvin

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by preinstalling the JAVA dependencies by install the `sparknlp` lib using maven.

In your Cluster-Libraries section, choose `install new`, then choose `maven`, and type in
`com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.0`